# css position adjust for header menu

Tags: css

ive issue with my header menu css , 
am try to center menu using following css code ,

```
.header ul.nav li {
        float:right;
        position-right:0px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 15px;


    }
    .header ul.nav li a{
        color: #fcd770;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding-right:50px;


    }
```

the out always is menu taking side in right , even when  i remove float:right its messed up , 
what am looking too is move the whole  group of the menu to center keep same space btween each link , 
here my my menu code

```
<ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users/">user</a></li>
            <li><a href="/support/">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Where did you get `position-right` from? It doesn't exist..

Comment: Is there some CSS missing here, for `.nav`/`.header`? Can you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? Make sure it shows your problem.

Comment: check out full demo  sudanesetweeps.com/new/index3w.php

Comment: You have some JavaScript above the doctype. Make sure `<!DOCTYPE html>` is on the **very first line**, otherwise you'll have problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `.header ul.nav`, add `text-align: center`.

On `.header ul.nav li`, remove `float:right` and the non-existent `position-right:0px;`, then add `display: inline-block`.

If you need to support IE7, use this for `display: inline-block`:

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1
```